# How to enable s3 server access logging using the boto3 sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use the boto3 SDK to enable server access logging through python. However, I keep getting the error of:

> You must give the log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket

I know I need to add permissions to that group, but I don't know how to do that through the Python SDK.

I've tried following [Enabling Logging Programmatically - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/enable-logging-programming.html) but I was unable to convert it to Python.

I've additionally tried putting the Grantee and Permissions inside of the put_bucket_logging call, but to no avail.

Listed below is my function to attempt to do this resulting in the aforementioned error:

```py
def enableAccessLogging(clientS3, bucketName, storageBucket, 
                        targetPrefix):

    #Give the group log-delievery WRITE and READ_ACP permisions to the
    #target bucket
    acl = get_bucket_acl(clientS3, storageBucket)

    new_grant = {
        'Grantee': {
            'ID' : 'LogDelivery',
            'Type' : 'Group'
        },
        'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL',
    }

    modified_acl = copy.deepcopy(acl)
    modified_acl['Grants'].append(new_grant)

    setBucketAcl(clientS3, bucketName, modified_acl)

    response = clientS3.put_bucket_logging(
        Bucket=bucketName,
        BucketLoggingStatus={
            'LoggingEnabled': {
                'TargetBucket': storageBucket,
                'TargetPrefix': targetPrefix
            }
        }

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I made the new acl correctly, but when I applied it, I applied it to the source bucket not the targetBucket so for anyone else doing this, the correct code is below:

```py
def enableAccessLogging(clientS3, bucketName, storageBucket, 
                        targetPrefix):

    #Give the group log-delievery WRITE and READ_ACP permisions to the
    #target bucket
    acl = get_bucket_acl(clientS3, storageBucket)

    new_grant = {
        'Grantee': {
            'URI': "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery",
            'Type' : 'Group'
        },
        'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL',
    }

    modified_acl = copy.deepcopy(acl)
    modified_acl['Grants'].append(new_grant)

    setBucketAcl(clientS3, storageBucket, modified_acl)

    response = clientS3.put_bucket_logging(
        Bucket=bucketName,
        BucketLoggingStatus={
            'LoggingEnabled': {
                'TargetBucket': storageBucket,
                'TargetPrefix': targetPrefix
            }
        }

    )
```

Comment: Granting FULL_CONTROL is not necessary, or advisable.